# How can I redirect people from my Website to my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, web

I am building a website, and I would like to redirect people from my Website to my Facebook account (as contact information).

I have already tried to just grab the Facebook URL and stick it in, but it didn't work. Also, I tried to find a solution on developers.facebook but I came up with nothing.

Comment: What URL didn't work?

Comment: The one from my profile page

Comment: And what URL is that?